# How can I remove "border-top-width" css style?

Tags: css

Let's say I have a Button with the following CSS style:

```
Button {
    border:2px #eee solid;
    border-top-width: 5px;
}
```

This will generate a button that has a 2px border in color #eee, except the top border will be 5px in thickness.

Now, let's say I have another button that inherits this style, but for this new Button I would like to remove the border-top-width property.

So my question is, how can I set border-top-width to null or to listen to the default border style? The following doesn't work but shows what I'm trying to do:

```
Button.class-name {
    border-top-width: auto;
}
```

Note that in my situation, I can't just set the value to "2px". I need to remove the value entirely. I've tried "auto", "inherit", "initial", etc... and nothing seems to remove the "border-top-width" property...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS proposes an [`initial` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#initial) which would reset it to the default value for the browser.

There is no way (and no proposed way) to set it to the value set by the previous but one rule that set it.

If you want it to take the value from `border:2px #eee solid;` then you must explicitly set it to `2px`.

If you were using a CSS preprocessor, such as SASS, you could use a variable:

```
$defaultBorderWidth: 2px;
Button {
    border:$defaultBorderWidth #eee solid;
    border-top-width: 5px;
}
Button.class-name {
    border-top-width: $defaultBorderWidth;
}
```

You could also use this technique with [native CSS variables](http://caniuse.com/css-variables).

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like you must be correct. Thanks for the references and this is the best suggestion so far.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok — Hence my use of the word *proposes*.

Comment: @Quentin You and I know this. There's no reason to assume everyone else does.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the class to set the width of the button that should be 5px on top:

```
button {
    border:2px #eee solid;       
}

button.class-name {
    border-top-width: 5px;
}
```

You can, also, use the `:not()` CSS selector:

```
button{
    border:2px #eee solid;
}

button:not(.normal) {
    border-top-width: 5px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gE25f/3/)

Comment: In my system, I need to be able to remove the value at runtime if it's already set.

Comment: @Andrew I edited my answer. See if it works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this if you want your top border-top-width is null;

**HTML code**

```
<button>Press me</button>
<button>Hit me</button>
<button class="leave-me">Leave me</button>
```

**CSS code:**

```
button{
     border:2px #eee solid;
    border-top-width: 5px;
}

button.leave-me{
    border-top-width:initial;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/shoaibista/gE25f/)

Comment: This will set the border-top-width to 0px. I need to remove the property so the border is 2pm all around.

Comment: That way the `.leave-me` button would have no top border.

Comment: @Beterraba - yes, but I don't want it to have no top border. I want the property removed and to then have a border as defined by the first css value (in my example, this would be 2px).

Answer (score -1):

Eighter you put the border-top-width on your

```
button.class-name
```

Or instead of calling that property on the css, try calling it directly on your html.

Or, you can also, on the second button, call

```
border-top-width:2px;
```

Comment: In my question, I mentioned that I cannot explicitly set the value to 2px.

Comment: Then, soz. I don't know. Will search around, if i find something. I'l click

Comment: I also said in my original question that "auto" does not work.

Comment: I know, i eddited my coment. Guess i didn't go in time